# Checking if there exists a 'source' vertex

Tags: graphs, depth-first-search, topological-ordering

In a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ we denote a vertex $s\in V$ to be a 'source' if there exists in $G$ a path from $s$ to all other vertices $u \in V$.

The problem asks for an efficient algorithm to return the 'source', in case there isnt any, return false.

I've been able to come up with a naive approach to his problem:

$\forall v\in V$:

Do $DFS(v)$, mark $S_v$ to be the set of vertices contained in DFS tree starting at $v$

if $|S_v|=|V|$, return $v$

After doing this for all $v\in V$, if we finished looping, return false.

This algorithm runs in $O(|V|\cdot (|V|+|E|))$ which is far from what I'm looking for, however I am unsure how to improve this.

EDIT:

Since we know a DAG has a vertex $v$ which $degree_{in}(v)=0$, we can use this fact to solve this problem:

I've come up with a new algorithm with a $O(|V|+|E|)$ runtime:

1. perform tarjan's algorithm to find SCC's and create the quotient graph $G'$.

(since the quotient is a DAG, we can apply the topological sort algorithm)

2. perform a topological sort on $G'$, mark $v$ to be the first node after sorting
3. perform $BFS$ on the first node after sorting.
4. if any of the paths from $v$ to a node in $G'$ is of length $\infty$ (which means there isnt a path from $v$ to said vertex), return that there is no source vertex.
5. return $v$

I'm not completely sure about choosing the first vertex after sorting, but it's the only thing that came to mind.

Are there any ways to improve this/simplify in a way that the proving stage would be simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if you find all the *strongly connected components* in the graph, the *quotient graph* of the SCCs is a DAG.  In this DAG, if there is a meta-node that can reach all the other meta-nodes, you have your answer.

Check out the Wikipedia article on [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component).

A DAG has a *source* vertex if and only if it is connected and *only one vertex* has in-degree 0.

Comment: I'm unsure what a 'quetient graph' is, is it the graph of which you get once you reduce each SCC to a single vertex?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You "contract" each strongly connected component to one vertex and keep the in-neighborhood and out-neighborhood of the union of the vertices' respective neighborhoods.

Comment: [Quotient graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you check weather it is correct or that there is an example which disproves it?